# Find character strings with partial match

Tags: r

I have a list of character vectors as follows:

```
>seq
[[1]]
[1] "**GTCAGCCGATCGGGCGTCAG**TCGAACGGGGGGGGTAACTTGTCCGGGATCATGCGTCCGGCAAACCAAAGAGCCAACTGGGTTAAGAACGTGAGCCGGAGCCCACCCCACCTTTGCACTGCTGGGATTTGGAGGTTTCCT"
[[2]]
[1] "**GTCAGCCGATCGGGCGTCAG**TGGACAACAATCGTTTGACTGGCGCAGTCGTATCCGTGTACCGGCATCGGTCATAGGACTGAGCGACAAAATACATTTAAGGCGTTTAAAACCGGTCCAACTGGGATTTGGAGGTTTCCT"
```

My original list would consist of several more elements but I am highlighting only 2 for keeping it precise.

I want to find the position of all such character strings within the list which matches the characters in bold completely or partially. When I use grep for searching it looks for exact matches. For eg,

```
grep("GTCAGCCGATCGGGCGTCAG",seq)
```

returns their positions as 1,2 but I want to search in such a manner that even if the strings contained slightly different characters they would still return me their respective positions.

For eg, if I search with the following sequence where C has been changed to T in the 7th position and T has been changed to A in the 17th position, I should still be able to recover the string positions in the list as 1,2

```
     "GTCAGCTGATCGGGCGACAG"
```

ClustalW is a well known alignment tool in R. Is there a way to accomplish this using clustalW or any other means?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with positions? The results by grep does not contain the position but rather indicates that the first  and the second strings do contain the substring.

Comment: If I type in seq[[1]], R will return the 1st string in the list. That's what I mean by position. Grep tells me which strings possess the substring by providing the number of the strings within a list

Comment: Can you make your post reproducible? Share `dput(seq)` so we can copy the data. Also show expected output for the data shared.

Comment: instead of `grep` you could use `agrep` and define the cost accordingly